# Mercurial hosting with folders / repository organizing capabilities

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I'm currently using Bitbucket for my Mercurial repositories and it's working great. I would however like to be able to organize my repositories in folders, as having them all in one long list is a bit disorganized for my liking.

To be clear I'd like to be able to access my repositories kind of like this:

```
hg clone https://username@bitbucket.org/username/foldername/reponame
```

While (AFAIK) it is currently only possible to use a single reponame, no foldername.

Is there any Mercurial hosting provider that does this, or is there some other method that might help me organize my stuff?

I'm aware of subrepos and I might look into that, but it seems like a hackish solution to my problem (also one of the clusters I am working on uses an ancient Mercurial version from way before subrepos were added). Another possibility would be to have multiple user accounts for Bitbucket, but again that doesn't really scale well (I don't want to wind up with 10 accounts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use separate repositories.

[Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/) has a nice interface that supports multiple repositories.

> **Organize Your Code**
>
> Start simply by just creating the repositories you need for your
>   code. Kiln introduces branch repositories, repository groups, and
>   projects to help keep things organized as you develop your own
>   workflow.
>
> ...
>
> Repository Groups and Projects are there to help keep related code
>   grouped together. Whether your software project is large or small, it
>   can be really helpful to separate different parts of the code into
>   different repositories. What used to be accomplished with complicated
>   naming schemes is now accomplished with simple labels and
>   drag-and-drop organization.

Answer (score 1):

Kiln (kilnhg.com) has a concept of projects and groups for organizing repositories along with several other really cool features.

It is a commercial product, however. (Your question didn't mention whether or not that was a problem for you.)

Comment: Thank you, sylvanaar seems to have been a little quicker with the same suggestion. Kiln seems to provide all I need in the free edition, so I think it will be a very good solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can obtain this using Bitbucket is to create a single repository named "foldername" and put the sub-repository inside this 'root repository'. This however is not the best practice according to the mercurial philosophy. Also, you will have a single bitbucket panel as per a single repository.

You can then use the mercurial feature Suprepositories to manage the whole collection:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository

Read about the kind of layout you are looking for here:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UnderstandingMercurial
(point 6, at the end of the page)

Of course you can setup your personal mercural server to do this, but is a little bit tricky and I discourage it. If you wanto to try, you can start from here: 
http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/blog-series/git-mercurial/step-by-step-install-mercurial-server-on-ubuntu/